# How to change associated country with Linksys E1000?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, localization

I got a new router (Linksys E1000) which came from Dubai. I've successfully set the timezone on its configuration to the correct one (GMT +8) for Philippines (where I am at right now). The problem is, When I set my laptop to `Set time zone automatically using current location`, it loads for a little while then ends up setting my location to Dubai. This has not been an issue on my previous router at all and it correctly reported Philippines.

I was wondering if there was a way to change the associated country/location on the E1000.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned `Set time zone automatically using current location` so i expect you're using a Mac.

From "[About Location Services in OS X Lion and Safari 5.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5009)" it says OSX takes it's location `from local Wi-Fi networks` and `doesn’t personally identify you` so you took a WiFi-router from Dubai and OSX/Apple thinks you're still there :)

I don't know how you can request a change in location in Apples database (of your WiFi-router). Apple used to use the database from [Skyhook](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/submit_ap.php) but have since [switched to their own](http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/29/apple-location/).

Maybe if you connect with an iPhone to your WiFi, turn on GPS and go to the Apple maps application, tap your location to get the blue dot and wait a few seconds. Apple can now update its database. This should trigger an update in Apples database but it won't be instant. (It's not confirmed this will work)

For now you can also try disabling the `Location Services` (but I don't know if then the time is automatically updated but at least you can set your location):

In `System Preferences > Security > General tab` you can check `Disable Location Services`.

**Edit**: Someone [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4370143?start=0&tstart=0) did the following:

*This worked for me.  Go to the Apple Maps app on your iphone, ipod or ipad while on your wifi.  Touch the blue dot/pin showing our current wrong location.  Then touch the > arrow inside the blue circle to bring up the menu for that pin showing our wrong location.  Then select "Report a Problem".  Next, click "Pin is at incorrect location".  Then the next button.  You will be told to drag the pin to the correct location.  If you are a long way off, such as another state, it helps to zoom out, drag around and find your current location on the map.  Drop the pin and click send.  About 24 hours later, your home wifi will be corrected to your "new current" location on all your Apple devices.*

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an iOS device. My Android phone's Google Maps seem to pinpoint my location properly. The problem is when I try to use web services on any browser on the desktop and it tries to find my location,, it detects it as Dubai. This only happens on the desktop that has no GPS feature but on my phone with a GPS, it detects fine.

Comment: It's unfortunate the only way I now of how to update Apples database. You could invite some friends over with iPhones for a BBQ and use their phones :) I don't know a place in OSX to correct the position (which sends it to Apple to update the database).

Comment: You could also try (besides the BBQ) changing the SSID and MAC-Address of the router (if possible). It's should be the info Apple uses for its database.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should also uncheck "Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving changes",
click "Save Settings" and reboot the router.

You could also download the latest [firmware update](http://support.linksys.com/en-eu/support/routers/E1000/download) (09/17/2013)
and see if it behaves better.

If the parameters of the router are loused-up, the first step is to do a
factory reset to reinitialize all parameters to their default value.

If this doesn't work,
I wonder if the firmware that you have is not somehow tailored for Dubai,
so it would be worthwhile to update it anyway.

Comment: It is already unchecked. How do I know what version or date of the firmware I'm currently using?

Comment: You can see this by pointing your browser to the router dashboard: Firmware Version is on top-right. Current version seems to be 2.1.02 (Build 6). Beware of using the wrong router model number in the above download link.

Comment: Okay, mine says that very same version as well.

Answer (score 0):

The laptop is getting its location by using Apple's Location Services database.

Apple shows the router's MAC address as being in the old location.

Therefore, you may configure the router to have a new MAC address, then the Apple Location Services will not know where you are located.

To teach Apple where you are, you will most likely need to use an iOS device.  It might be worth trying to call Apple support on the phone, maybe they will be able to do something on their end.

Answer (score 0):

If I assumed the issue not with the router and its with your OS then there is a discussion went on time Zones in [Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2136789?start=45&tstart=0). Check it out. Its having various possibilities that could lead to false time zone.